# How to use vuetify 3 data table sort

Tags: javascript, sorting, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3, vuetify-datatable

I'm on Vuetify 3 and i have a v-data-table with some data inside and I'd like to be able to add a custom sort on some columns.
I've tried to add it in the header by putting a function in "sort" but I can't get the information back.

for test purpose i try with a return random and the sort function works fine.

what i want to do (in the headers):

```js
{
  title : "Title of the column",
  key: "myKey",
  sortable: true,
  sort: (a,b) => {
    //sorting algo
    return sortingResult
   },
},
```

but a and b are undefined

Comment: [Works ok in Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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). Provide more info for your use case